# serializable object giving FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: java, android

I am getting `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION` while trying to send custom Object which contains one string with encrypted audio file data.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);           
i.putExtra("customObj", customObj);
startActivity(i);
```

and trying to recieve the data using

```
customObject = (CustomClass) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("customObj");
```

Please let me know how to send customObj with audio file data which is huge in size.

for small size audio file data I am able to get the data into NextActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the audio file from activity to activity, have each activity read the file from disk (or from some sort of static cache, etc.) instead. There is a limit in how much information you can pass inside an activity intent's bundle extras, and the large size of the audio file is likely causing the application to crash.

Comment: I am getting that audio file data from server and am displaying that data in listview and onlistItem click am passing data related to that listitem to next activity, I don't want to save server data into local system which takes huge space of mobile disk

Comment: You can always save the file to disk in the application's cache directory, which you can retrieve by calling `getCacheDir()` (see [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)). Android will delete files stored here if storage space becomes limited.